# How can I write a file in tomcat folder?

Tags: java, file, tomcat, java-io, fileoutputstream

I have deployed my application in Apache Tomcat.

I  have a folder(assets) to save the files. So  want to write a file inside **webapps/assets**

I tried the following code for that

```
    private String uploadedFiles(MultipartFile files) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "../assets/users/image/" + files.getOriginalFilename();

    File file = new File(filePath);
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.close();
```

But i am getting **java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../assets/myfile.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)**

How can save this file?

Note: I want this kind of folder structure. Since I will save "../assets/myfile.png" in the database to access from the client application deployed in the same server.

Comment: is your application based on a framework or is pure java?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the tomcat home path with

```
System.getProperty( "catalina.base" );
```

You can then add to this your path, in your case `/webapps/assets`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but you should give bytes from Multipart files !
And such of kind

> ../assets/users/image/

is wrong. I think, you should start with root folder, or use `Paths.get()` nio.